# XML to xml to display the values efficiently

Tags: xml, xslt

could someone shed some light on how to get the data for my xml_2
myxml1 looks like below, how can i get the heading and values for emp id/name.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <xX:Doc>
<XX:Head style="Topic">
    <b type="para">Employee</b>
</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="Subheading">
<b>Emp Details</b>
</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="EMP_ID">888999</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="EMP_NAME">JOSH</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="HIRE_DATE">01/01/2000</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="Subheading">
<b>HOBBIES</b>
</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="h1">swimming</XX:Head>
<XX:Head style="h2">travelling</XX:Head>
```

my xslt code as below

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" ></xsl:output>
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <empdata xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="employee.xsd"> 
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XML" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="xml" ></xsl:output>
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <empdata xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hr.xsd"> 
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </empdata> 
     </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='Topic']">
         <xsl:element name="Topic"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="." />                    
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='Subheading']">     
                    <xsl:for-each select="b">
                          <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                          </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='emp_id']">     
                  <xsl:element name="emp_id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='emp_name']">   
                  <xsl:element name="emp-name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>     
     <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='h1']">     
                  <xsl:element name="h1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
     <!--   etc...-->                 
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

now the issue is with newxml2.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <empdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XML"    
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hr.xsd">
       <topic>employee</topic> 
       <b>emp details</b> 
       <empid>888999</empid> 
        <empname>888999</empname> 
        <b>HOBBIES/b> 
        <h1>swimming</h1> 
        <h2>travelling</h2> 
         </empdata>
```

question: 
 how to code second part without repeating

any quick help appretiated

Question:how to code second part without repeating

any quick help appretiated

thanks,
jill

Comment: what kind of XSL code is that? two `<Stylesheet>` tags??!!

Comment: Remember to post a well-formed code

Answer (score 1):

Though not much clear with requirement I have designed it. Hope it works for you. Let me know if any modification you need in output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XML" version="1.0" xmlns:XX="http://www.w3.org">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="XX:Head">
    <xsl:element name="{@style}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="XX:Head[@style='Subheading']">
    <xsl:for-each select="b">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```